# Does deleting from a table of a h2 database handled by Hibernate corrupts the table?

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, sql-delete, kettle

Here a quick description of the system:

- A java 7 REST client receives jsons and write their parsed content into an h2 database via Hibernate.
- Some Pentaho Kettle Spoon 4 ETLs directly connect to the same database to read and delete a lot of entries at once.

This solution worked fine in our test environment, but in production (where the traffic is really higher because of course it is) the ETLs are often failing with the following error

```
Error inserting/updating row
General error: "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_A < ?  [50000-131]
```

and if I navigate the database I can indeed see that that table is not readable (*apparently because it thinks its lenght is -1?*). The error code `50000` is for "Generic" so is no use.

Apart from the trivial "*maybe h2 is not good for an Event Handler*", I've been thinking that the corruption could possible be caused by a confict between Kettle and Hibernate, or in other words that no one should delete from an Hibernate handled database without him knowing.

My questions to those more experienced then me with Hibernate are:

- Is my sopposition correct?
- Should I re-design my solution to also use the same restful Hibernate to perform deletes?
- Should I resign using h2 for such a system?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

The database is created by a simple sh script that runs the following command that basically uses the provided Shell tool to connect to a non existing db which by defalts creates it.

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp *thisIsAPath*/h2database/h2/main/h2-1.3.168-redhat-2.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -user $DB_USER -password $DB_PASSWORD -url jdbc:h2:$DB_FOLDER/Temp_SD_DS_EventAgent<<END
```

So all its parameters are set to version 1.3.168's defaults. Unfortunately while I can find the [current URL setting](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) I can't find where to look for that version's defauts and experimentals.

I also found the followings:

- According to the [tutorial](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html) `When using Hibernate, try to use the H2Dialect if possible.` which I didn't.
- The tutorial also says `Please note MVCC is enabled in version 1.4.x by default, when using the MVStore`. Does that mean cuncurrency is disabled/unsupported by default in this older case and this is the problem?
- The database is created with h2 version 1.3.168 but the consumer uses 1.4.197. Is this a big deal?

Comment: Why you're using an archaic version of H2 database that was released more than 10 years ago?

Comment: Sadly the servers run java 7 and I cannot change this thing...

Comment: H2 1.4.200 from 2019 and all earlier versions support Java 7 too, what is the point in use of 1.2.131? It's highly unlikely that somebody remembers something about behavior of entirely outdated versions.

Comment: The problem is similar: I have no control/authority on what version on whatever software is installed on the server, so sometimes I have to adapt to these ancient technologies...

Comment: You need to provide the complete stack trace of the exception and parameters of JDBC URL, if any. There were some experimental (at that point) flags, such as `MVCC` and `MULTI_THREADED`.

Comment: Nice observation. I edited the answer.

Comment: You should not ever try to open database created by 1.3.168 in 1.4.197. You need to export it into SQL in 1.3.168 (`SCRIPT TO 'filename.sql`), create a new empty database in 1.4.197 and populate it with data from that script (`RUNSCRIPT FROM 'filename.sql'`).

Comment: how are the two applications connecting? are they both connecting directly to the database-files on the file system? or are they connecting over the TCP ports? the client and driver versions matters. offhand, i would guess that you have two applications connecting directly to the database via the filesystem but that they are using two different versions...

Comment: @Nathan your guess is right: both applications connects to the db via file system. One only _writes via hibernate_, the other only _deletes via kettle_. My suspicion is that hibernate does not like that someone else it is not aware of is deleting.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on the credibility of h2 db.
But from application perspective, I think you should use locking mechanism - Optimistic or Pessimistic lock. This will avoid the conflict situations. Hope this answer helps to point in correct direction

[Article on Optimistic and Pessimistic locking](https://medium.com/@recepinancc/til-9-optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking-79a349b76dc8#:%7E:text=Optimistic%20Locking%20is%20when%20you,can%20start%20modifying%20the%20record.)